# Loop won´t excecute unless I step through it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, playing-cards

Let me start by saying sorry for my terrible grammar and spelling.

I have a MVC3 project that creates a Deck and adds 52 cards to it.
Then i added a shuffle function that only work´s when **I step through** the loop in the shuffle method.

In my class Deck i create an Array that holds 52 PlayingCard objects. 
Deck has a method that copies the Array to a List that is displayed in my View, 
and it has also a method that shuffles the list.

Not easy to explain but the code only runs **one time** unless i step through it.

My shuffle method in my Deck model.

```
 public void Shuffle()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
    {
        PlayingCard temp;
        temp = myDeck[i];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomNr = rnd.Next(51);
        myDeck[i] = myDeck[randomNr];
        myDeck[randomNr] = temp;
    }   
}
```

**Output after shuffle, whithout step through:**

***4     diamonds**
1    hearts
2    hearts
3    hearts
4    hearts
5    hearts
6    hearts
7    hearts
8    hearts
9    hearts
10   hearts
11   hearts
12   hearts
13   hearts
1    spades
2    spades
3    spades
4    spades
5    spades
6    spades
7    spades
8    spades
9    spades
10   spades
11   spades
12   spades
13   spades
1    clubs
2    clubs
3    clubs
4    clubs
5    clubs
6    clubs
7    clubs
8    clubs
9    clubs
10   clubs
11   clubs
12   clubs
13   clubs
1    diamonds
2    diamonds
**12     diamonds**
3    diamonds
5    diamonds
6    diamonds
7    diamonds
8    diamonds
9    diamonds
10   diamonds
11   diamonds
13   diamonds
*

**Output after step through 15 times:**

*2   spades
3    clubs
5    spades
3    diamonds
12   diamonds
13   hearts
11   hearts
1    spades
6    clubs
5    diamonds
1    clubs
12   hearts
7    clubs
13   spades
2    clubs
10   hearts
3    spades
4    spades
3    hearts
6    spades
7    spades
8    spades
9    spades
10   spades
11   spades
12   spades
8    hearts
7    hearts
1    hearts
2    hearts
4    clubs
5    clubs
9    hearts
6    hearts
8    clubs
9    clubs
10   clubs
11   clubs
12   clubs
13   clubs
1    diamonds
2    diamonds
4    hearts
4    diamonds
5    hearts
6    diamonds
7    diamonds
8    diamonds
9    diamonds
10   diamonds
11   diamonds
13   diamonds*

**Output after stepping through the entire loop:**

*10  hearts
6    clubs
8    hearts
5    hearts
5    clubs
7    diamonds
5    spades
11   diamonds
12   spades
12   clubs
8    diamonds
5    diamonds
1    clubs
9    spades
10   diamonds
12   hearts
8    spades
9    clubs
13   clubs
6    hearts
1    spades
11   spades
1    hearts
12   diamonds
4    clubs
3    clubs
8    clubs
9    diamonds
7    clubs
2    clubs
3    diamonds
1    diamonds
7    spades
10   spades
2    hearts
6    spades
13   spades
4    spades
2    spades
6    diamonds
4    hearts
2    diamonds
4    diamonds
11   clubs
7    hearts
11   hearts
3    spades
3    hearts
10   clubs
13   hearts
9    hearts
13   diamonds*

As shown the loop only runs when i step through it. 
I tried different loops, made a new project, move the shuffle function to the controller, nothing helps.

Anyone have any ideas how I should solve this?

Comment: Without even reading most of this, you are going to get issues using the `Random` class inside the loop, move it outside the loop (as in, initialize it once) and then call `Next` inside the loop. If you initialize it in a tight loop, the random seed can be the same as before thus it appears to not be "random".

Comment: Check if Memory operations are not doing something weird with loop iterator. `Console.Write` its value

Comment: "and let me start by saying sorry for my terrible grammar and spelling." Oh please, if you have been around here long enough as some of us, your spelling and grammar is actually a blessing.

Comment: When you say "the code only runs one time" is this based on what you observe? Stick a Debug.WriteLine in the loop and keep an eye on your output window.

Comment: @Adam The code runs through as shown in the debug output, but still it´s not shuffling more than the first index.

Comment: @Magnus I´m not used to write in english, beacuse 99% of my questions is answered when i search on it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample app around this and moving `Random rnd = new Random()` to outside the loop gives me the behaviour I'd expect.

The reason it only appeared to shuffle one card, in my opinion, is because the randomly generated value was the same value for the entire loop.

Comment: It works perfect thank you. I found an answer to my question, now that i know what to look for.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3053811/1717417