# While loop over a oledbdatareader needs a sleep so it doesn't get ahead of itself

Tags: c#, while-loop

In the method below, I leading data into a list from an excel file. I want SessionNo to change every time txnhdr.SessionNo changes. this is handled in the IF statement.

The method works sometimes, but at other times the inside of the IF is not hit and the Session doesn't change, UNLESS I put a Thread.Sleep, then it works every time.

I can't see that I'm missing anything.

```
 public static void LoadDataFromFile(string testXLDataFile, string sheetName)
    {
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\TestData\" + testXLDataFile;

        var connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';";
        var queryString = "select * from [" + sheetName + "]";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);

            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader txnReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            int? SessionNo = -1;
            int currSessionNo = -2;

            while (txnReader.Read())
            {                    

                var txnhdr = new TxnHeader(txnReader["HostIP"].ToString().Trim(), int.Parse(txnReader["SessionNo"].ToString().Trim()), txnReader["CustID"].ToString().Trim(), txnReader["GroupID"].ToString().Trim(), txnReader["ProfID"].ToString().Trim());

                if (currSessionNo != txnhdr.SessionNo)
                {
                    currSessionNo = txnhdr.SessionNo;
                    SessionNo = new Random().Next(999999, 999999999);
                }

               //the rest of the code does not reassign any of the above variables
               //but if I don't put a Thread.Sleep(100) here, then SessionNo will 
               //not be reassigned a new random number starting at random rows. 

              }//while
            }//using
          } //method
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unrelated to your database code.  You're creating a new instance of `Random` each time through the loop.

Create one instance of `Random` before the loop, and call `Next()` in the loop.

Comment: Random gets called only when the SessionNumber changes, that's what I want. If session number is the same for 5 rows, then Random gets called the first time and not again until it changes again.

Comment: You still need to create the `Random` outside the loop.  Call `Next` as needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try that when I get back to my dev machine. Still, I don't understand how the way I'm using Random would cause this kind of thing though. It's inside the IF. An explainer might come in handy, if you feel like it.

Comment: Got answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053807/random-number-in-a-loop